# SQL Server alter table to change TEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX) greatly increasing database size

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a SQL Server database thats about 18GB in size to change a significant number of `TEXT` columns to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

The problem I'm having is after executing all the `alter table` commands the database ends up being almost 26GB in size. I understand that from here using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` will alow the DB to grow more slowly but is there any way for me to prevent this bloating ?

Comment: Oh, don't create the same question here. Just flag it on SO and mods will migrate it here in an instant :-). Now somebody needs to merge/clean..etc.

Comment: Is the database larger or is the log very large?

Comment: Sorry Marian, understand now...

Comment: Aaron, the MDF file is much larger....almost 10GB larger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect this post will be of help to you.

[http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125040904/http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsperfblog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx)

Key facts:

- By default `TEXT` and `NTEXT` stores the text value in the LOB structure
- By Default `NVARCHAR(MAX)` stores the text value in the table structure (Unless it is over 8000 bytes)
- When you alter the column from the `TEXT`/`NTEXT` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, the way the data is stored is not changed, it updates the table metadata only.  The data structure is only changed the next time the value is changed.  This can be done immediately by running something like this:

  ```
   update mytable set mycolumn1 = mycolumn1
   where datalength(mycolumn1) <= 8000
  ```
- If you use the default table option setting for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, then the data in your table will be larger.

*- You will need to look at your table option settings and environment before changing the setting to what suits your needs.*

- Your table size will eventually shrink, if you follow your alter table statement with the update table statement.

In short, if you run the update statement, forcing the storage of the data structure to be changed, your database size will be smaller, as expected.

**EDIT**: As you have mentioned `TEXT` and not `NTEXT`, your gain in space would be less obvious than you might think.  `NTEXT` takes double the amount of space as what `TEXT` does, but at the same time, you should expect `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to take up around half the space as what `NTEXT` does.  By my calculation, you would see little change from your original database size.

---

> *Special credit to http://www.douglubey.com/*

Comment: could you sum up here the important facts, in case the link may become dead.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, TEXT vs. NTEXT will have an impact on the storage, but not by as much as you have suggested.

Comment: Thanks... I have been putting off joining for years now... Glad to be here.

Comment: Thanks RoKA, that has made a significant difference to a couple of the tables in question. I'm going to restore the database again and do it incrementally to see the affects. Thanks again.....

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 6):

Might be an oversight in your question, but you're saying TEXT to NVARCHAR(max) and not NTEXT to NVARCHAR(max). If this is what you're really doing, you're changing from ANSI to UNICODE and you shouldn't be surprised it takes more space (single byte characters vs. multi-byte characters).

Comment: Yes, thats what i'm doing ... although based on some simple calculations it wouldnt account for the size of the increase.

Comment: Have you tried with RoKa's suggestion?

Comment: @AidanLawless what calculations are these?  The size of the database should increase at least by the size of the existing `TEXT` field - going to unicode takes exactly twice the storage space of ANSI.

Comment: @JNK ... unless using compression in 2008 R2 or better, where Unicode compression will treat ASCII characters stored in NVARCHAR like VARCHAR.